# Clojure defn name as multiplier

Tags: clojure, defn

Could any one explain why in the following code the name of the function acts in the first part as a `*` (multiplier)?

```
(defn bar
     ([a b]   (bar a b 100))
     ([a b c] (* a b c)))
```

Giving `bar` two args `(bar 2 3)` yields `(* 2 3 100)`

Answer (score 5):

If might be easier to see what's going on if you reformat it slightly:

```
(defn bar
  ([a b]   (bar a b 100))
  ([a b c] (* a b c)))
```

This is a function with multiple arity - that is, it accepts more than one set of arguments. The first definition accepts two arguments named `a` and `b`, and second definition accepts three arguments named `a`, `b`, and `c`. When the first definition of the function is invoked it turns around and invokes the second definition of the function, passing in the `a` and `b` arguments which were given to the first definition, and sending the constant value 100 as the third argument. The second definition of `bar` simply takes the three arguments it's given and multiplies them together using `(* a b c)`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a function with two overloads - the first takes two arguments and the second three. The two-argument overload simply calls the three-argument version with 100 as the third argument.